# Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-import

I have imported eclipse project into android studio. When I creates new project in studio and run its working fine. But when I run imported project then I am getting below error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Here is my bulid.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
//    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.edelivery"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23

        multiDexEnabled true
//        compileOptions {
//            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
//            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
//        }


    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
//    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.1'

    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

    compile files('libs/PayPalAndroidSDK-2.9.10.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, change

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'`

with

```
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.1'
```

or

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
```

Please, change (if needed)

```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-X.X-all.zip
```

with

```
    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
```

Consider also upgrading (if you haven't done yet) upgrade Android Studio to the latest one

It should work.

Comment: I have not used distributionUrl

Comment: I forgot to add that distributionUrl is in `gradle-wrapper.properties`